# Как ускорить выполнение js 8 слайдеров на slick.js для оптимизации скорости на мобильных устройствах

Tags: slick.js, оптимизация-сайтов

Проверяется скорость страницы в https://developers.google.com/speed/pagespeed/insights/
Для мобильников показывает маленький бал.
Если на странице оставить 1 слайдер , то время обработки js 3000ms http://prntscr.com/oley4p.
Если поставить все 8 слайдеров, то  в два раза увеличивается время выполнения скриптов  http://prntscr.com/olf279. Подскажите может можно как то оптимизировать работу скриптов в мобильной версии?Для десктопной версии показывает нормально для 8 слайдеров http://prntscr.com/olf357

Comment: 8 слайдеров ... 12 секунд ... для кого сделан этот сайт? Дело ведь не в количестве слайдеров, а в количестве изображений для них, большую часть этих изображений даже терпеливый пользователь может и не увидеть вовсе.

Comment: В каждом слайдере 5 изображений по 15 кб, желание заказчика сделать 8 слайдеров) Пытаюсь его уговорить хотя бы на 4. Вопрос вообще в том , почему на мобильной версии скрипты отрабатывают в 6 раз медленнее

Comment: Предположение - пейджспидина имитирует соединение 3G.